# MVC Request Actionlink that was clicked in controller

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

I have actionlinks that do similar functions. How can I request which actionlink was just clicked in controller so I can put them all in same `TopRated` function like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Today", "TopRated")
@Html.ActionLink("30 Days", "TopRated")
@Html.ActionLink("Weekly", "TopRated")
@Html.ActionLink("All Time", "TopRated")
```

Instead of having them in 4 different functions like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Today", "Today")
@Html.ActionLink("30 Days", "TopRated30")
@Html.ActionLink("Weekly", "TopRatedWeekly")
@Html.ActionLink("All Time", "AllTimeTopRated")
```

controller:

```
 public ActionResult TopRated()
        {
            using (var context = new EntityDBContext())
            {
                //Request which actionlink was just clicked by user
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an enumerator of all the top rated periods:

```
public enum PeriodEnum
{
   Today,
   ThirtyDays,
   Weekly,
   AllTime
}
```

Your `TopRated` should receive a parameter of that enum type that you created earlier:

```
public ActionResult TopRated(PeriodEnum period)
{
    using (var context = new EntityDBContext())
    {
         //Request which actionlink was just clicked by user
    }
}
```

Finally your action links are going to look like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Today", "TopRated", new {period = PeriodEnum.Today})
@Html.ActionLink("30 Days", "TopRated", new {period = PeriodEnum.ThirtyDays})})
@Html.ActionLink("Weekly", "TopRated", new {period = PeriodEnum.Weekly})
@Html.ActionLink("All Time", "TopRated", new {period = PeriodEnum.AllTime})
```